# How do I select tag with a randomize id, but have a consistent word on it?

Tags: jquery

I have this project that needs some little tweak (i'm not the original author of the code). I just wanted to know how would i select a tag with an id that has a randomize id name (generated by the backend) on it but somehow in the middle of the id has a consistent word "thisfield".

```
   <input type="number" id="somerandomizealphanumerichere_thisfield_descriptioncodehere" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `_thisfield_` always appears in the id, you can use the query string

```
[id*="_thisfield_"]
```

to select inputs which have `_thisfield_` somewhere in their ID attribute. Example:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('[id*="_thisfield_"]');
console.log(input);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="somerandomizealphanumerichere_thisfield_descriptioncodehere" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `*=` selector as in `$("input[id*=_thisfield_]")`. Documentation can be found [here](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

**demo**

```js
console.log($("input[id*=_thisfield_]").val())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="somerandomizealphanumerichere_thisfield_descriptioncodehere" value="1" />
```

Comment: @Jorge no problem, happy to help

Comment: @Jorge If your question is solved, Consider any of those answers that solved your problem so other know what helped you.

Comment: both answers does solved the question. Thank You! But have to give it to the first answer.